# Create a variable in Prometheus/Grafana with all values selected by default

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm using Grafana with Prometheus as a Datasource.

I'm trying to create a variable with a filtered list of servers and I want to use this list to fix list of servers to display in my Dashboard.

My variable, named `servers_front`, is a query (`label_values(info_fqdn)`) with a regex to choose my servers `/.*_front/`

I want to use this full list of servers by default without displaying a combobox to choose which one I want to display.

Another requirement : If a new server that matches `/.*_front/` is created, I want the list is automatically updated

Answer (score 6):

Edit the variable
Variables > Edit > Selection Options >enable Include All option >Custom all value>`.*`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When saving dashboard you have an option to "save current variables", which means that currently selected value will be stored as a default when dashboard is loaded.
So if you have a templating variable with enabled "All" option you can save your dashboard ensuring "All" is selected (with option mentioned above enabled) and it should work.

Note that what is stored in dashboard is real "all" option and *not* an expanded list of all currently present values, so it should be dynamically expanded.

If you want that variable hidden then either you can hide the variable and save again after changing and saving its value or (if you have variable hidden from the start you can open url for dashboard with "&var-servers_front=All" appended (which will force variable to have "All" value and save dashboard with "save current variables".

Comment: I'll complete my question : with your solution the list is fixed. If a new server that match `/.*_front/` is created, I have to unhide all variables, select new server, hide again for all dashboards

Comment: Do you have Refresh set to "on dashboard load" or "on time range change" in the variable settings?